# How to add a picture on the left and text on the right, and keep them wrapped within a card using Reactstrap?

Tags: css, reactstrap

JS code

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './CountriesTable.module.css';

const CountriesTable = ({ countires }) => {

...

  return (
    <div className='table'>
      <Row>
        {countries.map((country) => (
          <Col xs="12" sm="6" lg="4">
              <Card className={styles.card}>
                <CardImg className={styles.icon} src={country.flag} alt={country.name} />
                <CardBody className={styles.body}>
                  <CardTitle tag="h5">{country.name}</CardTitle>
                  <div className='tag'>
                    {country.languages.map(({ name }) => (
                      <Badge color="secondary" pill>{name}</Badge>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <CardText>Test text message here</CardText>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
          </Col>
        ))}
      </Row>
    </div>
  )
}

...

export default CountriesTable;
```

CSS

```
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  margin-right: -12px;
  margin-left: -12px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: stretch;
  justify-content: space-around;
  padding: 8px;
  text-align: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 90%;
  background-color: var(--background-color-light);
  border-radius: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow);
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out, box-shadow 200ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 70px!important;
  min-width: 70px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.icon img {
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

.price {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}
```

I am using Reactstrap (https://reactstrap.github.io/) to use Bootstrap in React.

I am struggling to fit in the flags on the left-hand side, and the rest of the contents on the right-hand side of each card. Currently, I am facing two issues:

1. Some card contents go beyond the card boundary to the right.
2. For some cards, flags and other contents are still deployed vertically.

I am new to both CSS and React. Thank you so much for any advice in advance!

Comment: Give me a moment. Mate :) Let me see this by installing reactstrap first. For now try removing inline styles from the code. I mean these className={styles.card},className={styles.icon} and className={styles.body}. replace those with className="body" directly and similarly for others

Comment: How do your country array object look like. Share 1 object here for testing

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather Thank you! Here's the link to the api:  https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/all

Comment: I think it will work fine now, You only need to integrate API for countries now . Try it once. If you face difficulty I am here only :)
...

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you need to use `media queries` for different `break points` because each card gets dynamic country values. We need to look for best possible ways to do this.

I have created a neat demo for you and all the break points handled properly: [Responsive Cards](https://codesandbox.io/s/reactstrap-card-issue-forked-g5nf1)

```css
.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, 1fr);
  gap: 10px;
}

.card {
  display: flex;
  padding: 8px;
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px 10px #cccccc;
  font-weight: 500;
  transition: transform 200ms ease-in-out, box-shadow 200ms ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.icon {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 70px !important;
  min-width: 70px;
  margin-right: 4px;
}

.icon img {
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 100%;
}

.body {
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: left;
}

.price {
  text-align: right;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  }
}
```

```html
import React from "react";
import {
  Col,
  Row,
  Card,
  CardImg,
  CardBody,
  CardText,
  CardTitle,
  Badge,
} from "reactstrap";

import "./CardIssue.css";

const countries = [
  {
    name: "Afghanistan",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Åland Islands",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Albania",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Algeria",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "American Samoa",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "AndorrA",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Angola",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Anguilla",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
  {
    name: "Antarctica",
    flag: "https://picsum.photos/seed/picsum/200/300",
    languages: [{ name: "demo name" }],
  },
];
function CardIssue() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="table">
        <Row>
          {countries.map((country) => (
            <Col xs="12" sm="6" lg="4">
              <Card className={`card`}>
                <CardImg
                  className={`icon`}
                  src={country.flag}
                  alt={country.name}
                />
                <CardBody className={`body`}>
                  <CardTitle tag="h5">{country.name}</CardTitle>
                  <div className="tag">
                    {country.languages.map(({ name }) => (
                      <Badge color="secondary">{name}</Badge>
                    ))}
                  </div>
                  <CardText>Test text message here</CardText>
                </CardBody>
              </Card>
            </Col>
          ))}
        </Row>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CardIssue;
```